# Any way to include knockoutjs observable values in standard mvc form post?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, knockout.js

I am using ASP.NET 4, MVC3, EF 4.3 (Code first) and knockout JS. I am currently working on the create and edit forms for one of my more complicated models. This has various fields attached to it, as well as several collections for related objects (many-to-many). I'll pose my question for the edit scenario, as this is the harder of the two.

I would like the user to be able to edit all of the fields of the model, which I have put in a viewmodel. For displaying and adding additional Skills (one of the many-to-many collections) I have decided to use knockoutjs to great effect, which displays the serialized initial objects of the collection nicely as well as allowing me to add more.

My problem is how to save this rather complicated model by sending it back to the controller. As many of my fields can be represented in the view by standard HTML helpers nicely, I would like to avoid multiple AJAX posts or binding every single field to a ko.observable(array). What I really want is to take only the many-to-many collections, bind them to ko.observablearrays, and somehow send them back as part of the standard strongly typed mvc view form post.

Is this even possible? And if so, how would I approach it? I'd really appreciate any help, my research so far has produced no useful results. Am willing to post code snippits if that helps to better describe the problem.

edit: sample viewmodel for edit form as requested

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    [NotMapped]
    public class JobViewModel
    {
        public int JobID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        // Foreign Keys
        [Display(Name = "Hiring Manager")]
        [Required]
        public string HiringManagerID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Assigned User")]
        public string AssignedUserID { get; set; }


        //Collections for many-to-many properties
        public List<JobSkillViewModel> JobSkills { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my ViewModel held in the collection:

```
namespace MyProjectModels
{
    [NotMapped]
    public class JobSkillViewModel
    {
        public int SkillID { get; set; }
        public int LevelID { get; set; }

        public string SkillName { get; set; }
        public string LevelDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of a model you are using

Comment: I have recently done a very similar thing (not using knockout however), I send the data as JSON to the controller which is able to bind it to a model defined on the server. We used newtonsoft json.net for the serialization and de-serialization. Not sure if this helps or not!

Comment: Model added for base viewmodel and viewmodel of collection.

Comment: @Magrangs Did you find any way to avoid serializing and mapping the entire class? I have a LOT (more than in sample) of fields in the form. What I'm trying to do is set the js variable that holds the JobSkill collection to a standard MVC form variable so I can return it in a normal post. If that's not possible, I'd settle for an easier way to include the whole form in a JSON post.

Comment: Yes, you can add an attribute to the property which will tell JSON.net to ignore it when serialising and de-serialising. (http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size.aspx)

Comment: One possibility is to send the ID's of the Jobskills as an array rather than the objects themselves, you can then have some server side code which deals with them. So your view model would contain an IEnumerable of int (this also simplifies your viewmodel). Some other process later on down the line can construct the actual objects based on those ids' maybe?

Comment: My issue in that case is how to send that array along with the rest of the standard mvc form post (@Html.Beginform()). Otherwise I have to take every view field and bind/set it to a javascript variable, and then post it all as json, which seems clunky and hopefully unecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing it this way but if you feel you must post with the form. Why not simply serialize the collection as JSON into a hidden form field.

```
<input name="something" type="hidden" data-bind="text: collectionToJson" />
```

Your collectionToJson method would call `ko.toJSON` or the mapping equivalent and then you would have to handle deserialization yourself server side.

I don't think you are doing to find a nice clean way to post back via a form **AND** model bind. If I were you I would bind the whole form to a json model and post back a complete well formed json object for automatic model binding. The resultant code on the server-side would be much cleaner IMHO.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you're certainly right that there isn't a nice and clean way to post back with a form and model bind. This is definitely one way to do it though, thanks.